# Firebase login with AngularDart in Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, dart, chromium, angular-dart, dart-pub

I am testing a web app of firebase login with angular Dart in Chrome browser at localhost, but while clicking on the `sign-in` the popup for login gets disappeared within 1 sec and doesn't result with successful login. While testing it on Chromium it's working.
Can anyone tell what should I do to fix this?

firebase_service.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart' as fb;

@Injectable()
class FirebaseService {
  fb.User user;
  fb.Auth _fbAuth;
  fb.GoogleAuthProvider _fbGoogleAuthProvider;

  FirebaseService() {
    fb.initializeApp(
      apiKey: "AIzaSyBOShlCgUeqTL99n32bjWdNlkH1RPk9Xx4",
      authDomain: "my-app.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://my-app.firebaseio.com",
      storageBucket: "my-app.appspot.com",
    );

    _fbGoogleAuthProvider = new fb.GoogleAuthProvider();
    _fbAuth = fb.auth();
    _fbAuth.onAuthStateChanged.listen(_authChanged);
  }

  void _authChanged(fb.User event) {
    user = event;
  }

  Future signIn() async {
    try {
      await _fbAuth.signInWithPopup(_fbGoogleAuthProvider);
     }
    catch (error) {
      print("$runtimeType::login() -- $error");
    }
  }


  void signOut() {
    _fbAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

app_component.html

```
    <header class="material-header shadow">
    <div class="material-header-row">
        <material-button icon
                         class="material-drawer-button" (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
            <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
        </material-button>
        <span class="material-header-title">{{appTitle}}</span>
        <div class="material-spacer"></div>
        <nav class="material-navigation">
            <material-button class="material-drawer-button" icon
                             materialTooltip="Notifications"
                             (trigger)="">
                <material-icon icon="notifications"></material-icon>
            </material-button>
            <div id="popup-sign-out" class="popup-user" *ngIf="fbService.user != null">
                <material-button class="material-drawer-button" icon
                                 popupSource
                                 #source="popupSource"
                                 materialTooltip="More options"
                                 (trigger)="basicPopupVisible = !basicPopupVisible">
                    <material-icon icon="more_vert"></material-icon>
                </material-button>
                <material-popup defaultPopupSizeProvider
                                enforceSpaceConstraints
                                [source]="source"
                                [(visible)]="basicPopupVisible">
                    <div header class="custom-header">
                        <img id="popup-user-image" [src]="fbService.user?.photoURL">
                        <div class="user-detail">
                            <div id="user-name">{{fbService.user?.displayName}}</div>
                            <div id="email">{{fbService.user?.email}}</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div group class="custom-popup-body">
                        <material-list class="popup-list" size="3">
                                       <div group>
                                <material-list-item class="sign-out-button"
                                                    *ngIf="fbService.user != null"
                                                    (trigger)="fbService.signOut()">
                                    <material-icon icon="exit_to_app" [style.color]="iconColor"
                                                   class="material-list-item-primary" aria-hidden="true">
                                    </material-icon>
                                    Sign out
                                </material-list-item>
                            </div>

                        </material-list>
                    </div>
                </material-popup>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <nav class="material-navigation">
                <div id="sign-in" class="user" *ngIf="fbService.user == null">
                    <material-button raised class="sign-in-button" (trigger)="fbService.signIn()">
                        <img class="google-icon" src="g-logo.png"/>
                        Sign In
                    </material-button>
                </div>

                <div id="sign-out" class="user" *ngIf="fbService.user != null">
                    <img id="header-user-image" [src]="fbService.user?.photoURL">
                </div>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/angular_components.dart';
import 'package:yns_app/services/firebase_service.dart'; 

@Component(
  selector: 'my-app',
      styleUrls: const [
    'app_component.css',
'package:angular_components/src/components/app_layout/layout.scss.css',
  ],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: const [
    materialDirectives,
    DeferredContentDirective,
    MaterialButtonComponent,
    MaterialIconComponent,
    MaterialPersistentDrawerDirective,
    MaterialToggleComponent,
    MaterialListComponent,
    MaterialListItemComponent,
    ClickableTooltipTargetDirective,
    DarkThemeDirective,
    MaterialIconTooltipComponent,
    MaterialInkTooltipComponent,
    MaterialPaperTooltipComponent,
    MaterialPopupComponent,
    MaterialTooltipDirective,
    MaterialTooltipTargetDirective,
    MaterialTooltipSourceDirective,
    NgIf,
    Search,
    NameGenerator,
 ],
  providers: const [
    materialProviders,
    popupBindings,
    DefaultPopupSizeProvider,
  ],
)
class AppComponent {
  final FirebaseService fbService;
  bool basicPopupVisible = false;
  bool end = false;

  String get tooltipMsg => 'All the best messages appear in tooltips.';

  String get longString => 'Learn more about web development with AngularDart '
  'here. You will find tutorials to get you started.';

  AppComponent(FirebaseService this.fbService);
}

@Injectable()
PopupSizeProvider createPopupSizeProvider() {
  return const PercentagePopupSizeProvider();
}

@Directive(selector: '[defaultPopupSizeProvider]', providers: const [
  const Provider(PopupSizeProvider, useFactory: createPopupSizeProvider)
])
class DefaultPopupSizeProvider {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

connect the domain or the sub-domain to the hosted project, under the Hosting section.